# Using SignalR with Angular and ASP.NET Core gives handshake error after publishing to the domain

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have this Angular project which uses SignalR in ASP.NET Core. Everything works correctly on local machine, but when I publish the project to the host it gives this error:

[image]

In the back-end the ASP.NET code is like this:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                        {
                            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                            {
                                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                                    .GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                                ValidateIssuer = false,
                                ValidateAudience = false,
                                ValidateLifetime = true,
                                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero //the default for this setting is 5 minutes
                            };
                            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                            {
                                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                                {
                                    if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                                    {
                                        context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                                    }
                                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                                },
        
                                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                                {
                                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
        
                                    // If the request is for our hub...
                                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                                        (path.StartsWithSegments("/chart")))
                                    {
                                        // Read the token out of the query string
                                        context.Token = accessToken;
                                    }
                                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                                }
        
                            };
                        });
    
    services.AddSignalR();
    
                services.AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                    options.Filters.Add(new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute());
                })
                    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                    .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                    {
                        opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    });
                services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                        builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
                });
                services.AddAntiforgery(antiforgeryOptions =>
                {
                    antiforgeryOptions.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                    antiforgeryOptions.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
                });
app.UseAntiforgeryToken();

            

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseAuthentication();
           
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChartHub>("/chart");
            });


            app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ""))
            });
            app.UseMvc();
```

The back-end app works on port 5000 of the host and the host has nginx.
On the client side also I have this code:

```
private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  public startConnection(): Observable<HubConnection> {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl('http://mydomain/chart',
                            {
                              accessTokenFactory: () => this.authService.getJwtToken()
                            })
                            .build();
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));
    return of(this.hubConnection);
  }
```

Comment: Have you enabled WebSockets in nginx?

Comment: So it could be the reason? let me check it